# Can't figure out callback on $.get to read text file into an array

Tags: javascript

I just want to get data from this text file, parse it a bit, and toss it into a couple of arrays. The asynchronous nature of aJax (which I didn't even know I was using...?) means that the array is still being populated before I try to access it. This seems to create a totally useless situation to me, as I need to access the arrays at different times during the users visit to the site. Any ideas?

```
var words = new Array();
var sylls = new Array();
var csv_file = new Array(); // for word arrays

$(document).ready(function(){
    readWords( addWords );
});

function readWords( process ) {
        $.get('terms.csv', function(data){
                csv_file = data.split('\n');
                    // csv file is now in an array, split into seperate word array and syllable array
                    for (var i = 0; i < csv_file.length; i++) {
                        var both = csv_file[i].split(',');  // split at the comma
                        words[i] = both[0]; // populate word array
                        sylls[i] = both[1]; // populate syllable array
                        //put_word(words[i], sylls[i]);

                    };

            });   
    process(words, sylls);
}

function addWords(w, ss){
    console.log(w);
}
```

this all eventually returns an empty array.

EDIT--SOLUTION:

I'm not sure why no one suggested this before, but for those of you as frustrated with ajax as I am, here is the easy solution!

```
var words = new Array();
var sylls = new Array();
var csv_file = new Array(); // for word arrays

$(document).ready(function(){
    get_words();

});

function get_words() {


        $.get('terms.csv', function(data){
            //async: false;
            csv_file = data.split('\n');
                // csv file is now in an array, split into seperate word array and syllable array
                for (var i = 0; i < csv_file.length; i++) {
                    var both = csv_file[i].split(',');  // split at the comma
                    words[i] = both[0]; // populate word array
                    sylls[i] = both[1]; // populate syllable array
                    //put_word(words[i], sylls[i]);
                };
            })
        .done(function() {
            // once it's done DO THIS STUFF
        });

}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn how promises, deferreds and callbacks work, and write your code so it works ***with*** the async nature of ajax calls, not against it.

Comment: So any suggestions here?

Comment: you're process function is outside the callback, so the process function will get called before the callback, you need to move it inside the callback function

Comment: This is the same as your earlier question. Please don't do that.

Comment: CSgoose: Where precisely should I put 'process(words,sylls)'?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `process(words, sylls);` is outside the `$.get()` block. `.$.get()` is an async (by default) request so when your program invokes it, it immediately returns and executes `process()` without having the necessary data.
Just add the `process()` invocation right before the end of the `$.get()` block.